# Ubuntu 14.04 Call Trace

Tags: kernel, 14.04, log

I am seeing a Call Trace in `kern.log` - system will shutdown cleanly

```
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743373] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 26176 at /build/buildd/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/drivers/usb/host/ehci-hcd.c:1038 ehci_endpoint_reset+0x101/0x110()
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743374] clear_halt for a busy endpoint
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743376] Modules linked in: cdc_acm hidp pci_stub vboxpci(OF) vboxnetadp(OF) vboxnetflt(OF) vboxdrv(OF) ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 bridge stp llc bnep rfcomm binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_hdmi xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 arc4 ipt_REJECT xt_LOG iwldvm snd_hda_codec_idt xt_multiport mac80211 pcmcia xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype ppdev dell_wmi sparse_keymap nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_state snd_hda_intel dell_laptop snd_hda_codec nvidia(POF) snd_hwdep ip6table_filter dcdbas ip6_tables snd_pcm nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast snd_seq_midi nf_nat_ftp nf_nat iwlwifi snd_rawmidi btusb nf_conntrack_ftp snd_seq_midi_event uvcvideo nf_conntrack bluetooth videobuf2_core i7core_edac snd_seq joydev videodev yenta_socket iptable_filter pcmcia_rsrc edac_core videobuf2_vmalloc ip_tables pcmcia_core cfg80211 videobuf2_memops snd_timer psmouse x_tables snd_seq_device serio_raw lpc_ich snd parport_pc soundcore snd_page_alloc video mei_me mei wmi
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: mac_hid coretemp lp parport hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid mmc_block ahci libahci e1000e firewire_ohci sdhci_pci firewire_core sdhci crc_itu_t ptp pps_core
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743450] CPU: 0 PID: 26176 Comm: pool Tainted: PF          O 3.11.0-18-generic #32~precise1-Ubuntu
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743452] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude E6510/0N5KHN, BIOS A05 08/10/2010
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743453]  000000000000040e ffff8801b3ff3cc8 ffffffff8173d60f 0000000000000007
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743457]  ffff8801b3ff3d18 ffff8801b3ff3d08 ffffffff8106540c ffff8801b3ff3ce8
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743460]  ffff880220759a84 0000000000000282 ffff880220759800 0000000000000003
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743463] Call Trace:
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743470]  [<ffffffff8173d60f>] dump_stack+0x46/0x58
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743475]  [<ffffffff8106540c>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8c/0xc0
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743478]  [<ffffffff810654f6>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x46/0x50
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743481]  [<ffffffff81051089>] ? default_spin_lock_flags+0x9/0x10
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743484]  [<ffffffff8156a6e1>] ehci_endpoint_reset+0x101/0x110
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743489]  [<ffffffff81553945>] usb_hcd_reset_endpoint+0x25/0x70
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743493]  [<ffffffff81554f18>] usb_reset_endpoint+0x28/0x40
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743496]  [<ffffffff815559fe>] usb_clear_halt+0x6e/0x80
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743499]  [<ffffffff8155ed6e>] proc_clearhalt+0x6e/0x90
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743502]  [<ffffffff8156112a>] usbdev_do_ioctl+0x91a/0xc50
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743507]  [<ffffffff810c8883>] ? futex_wake+0x113/0x130
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743510]  [<ffffffff8156148e>] usbdev_ioctl+0xe/0x20
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743513]  [<ffffffff811c6eac>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x7c/0x2f0
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743516]  [<ffffffff810ca662>] ? SyS_futex+0x142/0x1a0
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743518]  [<ffffffff811c71b1>] SyS_ioctl+0x91/0xb0
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743523]  [<ffffffff817521dd>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
Apr 14 20:58:00 kernel: [ 4742.743525] ---[ end trace 81f54da6ba3c1276 ]---
```

Comment: 12.04 as a tag and 14.04 in the title? and what is the question? ;)

Comment: could not add a 14.04 tag. and the question is what does the Call trace indicate

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `ulatency` package which fixed it.